# I am getting error when trying out Substrate's "Create a Pallet" Tutorial

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

[image]

Module is not recognised when i try to build my node after creating my pallet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your pallet is on the same version of Substrate as the one defined in runtime/Cargo.toml.

You are probably using the Frame v2 (aka Substrate 3.0.0) in your runtime, so it expects a Pallet (not Module), even if your pallet is actually written following Frame v1 syntax (Frame v2 is backwards compatible with v1).
Some more info [here](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/pallets)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. My version in my pallet is the same as that defined in my node. And this was the tutorial i followed

https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-a-pallet/

Did everthing the tutorial asked me too

Comment: line 295 Module => Pallet